# Moving a website from Drupal to Wordpress

Tags: migrations

i want to move a website from drupal to wordpress, keeping the hosting provider the same (siteground). please bear in mind my knowledge in these matters is very rudimentary (i have published a blog on wordpress before but never attempted a migration and have zero knowledge of drupal!).

this plugin FG Drupal to Wordpress comes highly rated. in the installation process it includes a step:

Configure the plugin settings. You can find the Drupal database parameters in the Drupal file sites/default/settings.php

But i am at a loss where to find this, i am logged into the dashboard of the website as administrator. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Pretty off topic, migrations to other platforms is entirely in your hands. There may be tools, there may not be tools, but its always scriptable - which is up to you. Its not about platform X or Y, its all stored in a database in the end, make the two talk.

Comment: The instructions mention looking for the settings.php file on the local file system of the server. If you do not have access to the file system, then this information may be available to you through your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are migrating away from Drupal to WordPress, it would seem that this is a more appropriate question for a WordPress forum.

Echoing Kevin's advice in the comment above, the best place for you to start would be by learning a little bit about databases and the Structured Query Language (SQL) used to get data into and out of them:

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql

Once you understand some basic stuff about database administration, you'll have a much easier time migrating content from one database to another, no matter what Content Management System (CMS) you are using.

In particular, you seem to be stuck configuring your plugin because you cannot find the Drupal database parameters. You won't find this information anywhere in the Drupal admin user interface.

> You can find the Drupal database parameters in the Drupal file `sites/default/settings.php`

That is a plain text file on the server. To read it, you'll need to access the server via SSH, FTP, or some other method, depending on your hosting. (You'll want to do some research about these things, too.)

Then, inside the Drupal document root on the server, you will find a directory called `sites`, which contains a directory called `default`, inside which you will find the `settings.php` file.

When you read this file, you will find the super secret database authentication tokens that your plugin needs to help automate the migration.

Depending on your Drupal version and hosting, it may look something like this:

```
  // Database.
  $databases['default']['default'] = array(
    'database' => 'DATABASE',
    'username' => 'USERNAME',
    'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'port' => 3306,
    'prefix' => '',
  );
```

Never share this info online, by the way.

There's more to website administration than just using the admin user interface of a CMS. You'll need to understand some basic concepts about the PHP code that you are running on the server -- not necessarily how to edit it, but at least how to view it.

Until you know some basic things like that, you'll have an easier time migrating your content by cutting and pasting articles manually between the old site and the new site.

Comment: Also, since the data structures are entirely different, its unlikely youll find a bulletproof automation tool. Best to just go heads down and do it.